# Topology Manager | How to create multiple Topology Environments

Tags: topology-manager, web8

I am setting up Staging and live publishing targets using the same discovery service but but it throwing error while running script.
1.  I have set up the topology type using the command

> Add-TtmCdTopologyType -Id StagingAndLiveType -Name "Staging and Live" -EnvironmentPurposes @("Staging","Live")
>   [image]
>   2. I am now trying to create two topology environment using the command
>
> Add-TtmCdEnvironment -Id StagingEnv -EnvironmentPurpose Staging -DiscoveryEndpointUrl http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc -AuthenticationType OAuth -ClientId
>   cmuser -ClientSecret XXXXXX

but its throwing error

[image]

If anybody can share some guidelines to set up multiple Targets ?

Comment: The error message is specifying that the DiscoveryEndpointUrl is not unique, that means it is already in use. Have you created 2 different discovery services for your for Staging and Live environment? Can you just hit Get-TtmCdTopology and check the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For creating multiple environment first you have to create multiple instances of discovery service. What I understand from the  error message is DiscoveryEndpointUrl is already in used by one environment.

So you have to create a new instance of discovery service first then try to add it.

Comment: I followed these steps-

Comment: I have 1 instance of discovery service installed on 8082 port.
I followed these steps-
1. Updated the ports of discovery and token service in quickinstall.ps1 script in contentdelivery\resources\quickinstall
2. Updated the port of discovery and tken service in  cd_storage_config file in \roles\discovery\standalone\config path
3. Changes rule and oAuth tag to false in cd_ambient.xml file
4. Running the script again

.\quickinstallStaging.ps1 -target-folder C:\SDL_WebServices  -discovery-url "http://localhost:9082/discovery.svc" -enab
le-discovery

Comment: It says WARNING: Service 'SDLWebDiscoveryService' already exists in system.
Service 'SDLWebDiscoveryService' already started.

Comment: change the name of the discovery service. and change the port no also in the script and run it again.

Comment: By the way it is not a good practice to stop the OAuth and Rules but you can do it just for practice

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is you cannot have two Windows Service with the same name.

You should change the  **$name="SDLWebDeployer"** and **$displayName="SDL Web Deployer"** in your powershell script before installing the second Content Deployer.

You can use in Deployer2\bin folder installService.ps1.

If you have to delete some service you can use UninstallService.ps1 this script keeps your configuration files (does not delete).

I hope help you.